# Is static_cast creating new child object?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting, static-cast

This code runs fine, when it should have a run-time error, since i haven't instantiated a derived class object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    void walk() { cout << "person walking" << endl; }
};
class Employee :public Person {
public:
    void work() { cout << "employee working" << endl; }
};
void main() {
    Person* p = new Person();
    Employee* e = static_cast<Employee*>(p); 
    e->work();// this is working - but why? it should fail at runtime
}
```

If static_cast only casting the pointer, how is it possible to call a child member function?
At what point is the child instantiated?
Is static_cast also instantiating objects?

Comment: "*it should fail at runtime*" Why should it? Undefined behavior is *undefined*. That can include "appears to 'work' by some definition."

Comment: Your main should return `int`,not `void`

Comment: It must be one of the commonest newbie assumptions that invalid programs **must** produce runtime errors. In a fair world it would be true, but the world is not fair, and it's only the case that invalid programs **may** produce runtime errors.

Comment: Now add an array of million `int`s to `Employee`, and attempt to clear it to zeroes, and see how well that works, if you're interested in seeing your code crash.

Comment: Your code has memory leak, every `new'd` there must be `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Your assertion that your code should "crash at runtime" is, unfortunately, wrong. Your code exhibits undefined behaviour meaning that it could do literally anything. In this case I expect it works because the address of the function is the same in both objects but really, it could be for any reason.

Comment: Neither method accesses the object they are being called on. Make them use the `this` pointer to access member data and you are more likely to see side effects occur, which may include the expected crashes.